# beautiful soup crawling with python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Hi I have question while crawling some stuff in the tags.
 Through the bs4, I am able to contact right before the below div tag.
 But what I actually need is data-lat and data-lng. Those are not text so I cannot use get_text(), and
 I'm not sure what helper function in bs4 can extract those inner data in the tag.

```
<div id="map" class="main_content embedded-content" data-lat="37.542560322393925" 
 data-lng="127.01606371950948">
```

Answer (score 5):

You can select the div element, and then get all its attributes via [attrs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)  property

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """<div id="map" class="main_content embedded-content" data-lat="37.542560322393925"  data-lng="127.01606371950948">"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> div  = soup.find("div", id = 'map')
>>> div.attrs
{'data-lng': '127.01606371950948', 'data-lat': '37.542560322393925', 'id': 'map', 'class': ['main_content', 'embedded-content']}
>>> div.attrs.get('data-lng',0.0)
'127.01606371950948'
>>> div.attrs.get('data-lat',0.0)
'37.542560322393925'
```

Comment: Or, simpler, `div.get('data-lng',0.0)`.